# why android alarm receiver is not working

Tags: android

I downloaded the scheduler example from android developer site. I have two package one package have three classes 
 com.example.android.scheduler----sampleSchedulerService and SampleAlarmReceiver and SampleBootReceiver
and another package is com.example1, has MainActivity class.

SampleSchedulerrService.java code as follows

```
package com.example.android.scheduler;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * This {@code IntentService} does the app's actual work.
 * {@code SampleAlarmReceiver} (a {@code WakefulBroadcastReceiver}) holds a
 * partial wake lock for this service while the service does its work. When the
 * service is finished, it calls {@code completeWakefulIntent()} to release the
 * wake lock.
 */
public class SampleSchedulingService extends IntentService {
    public SampleSchedulingService() {
        super("SchedulingService");
    }

    public static final String TAG = "Scheduling Demo";
    // An ID used to post the notification.
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    // The string the app searches for in the Google home page content. If the app finds 
    // the string, it indicates the presence of a doodle.  
    public static final String SEARCH_STRING = "doodle";
    // The Google home page URL from which the app fetches content.
    // You can find a list of other Google domains with possible doodles here:
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Google_domains
    public static final String URL = "http://www.google.com";
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
         Log.i("EFAIR","in onhandleintent");
        // sendNotification(getString(R.string.doodle_found));
         sendNotification(intent);
        /*// BEGIN_INCLUDE(service_onhandle)
        // The URL from which to fetch content.
        String urlString = URL;

        String result ="";

        // Try to connect to the Google homepage and download content.
        try {
            result = loadFromNetwork(urlString);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, getString(R.string.connection_error));
        }

        // If the app finds the string "doodle" in the Google home page content, it
        // indicates the presence of a doodle. Post a "Doodle Alert" notification.
        if (result.indexOf(SEARCH_STRING) != -1) {
            sendNotification(getString(R.string.doodle_found));
            Log.i(TAG, "Found doodle!!");
        } else {
            sendNotification(getString(R.string.no_doodle));
            Log.i(TAG, "No doodle found. :-(");
        }*/
        // Release the wake lock provided by the BroadcastReceiver.
        SampleAlarmReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
        // END_INCLUDE(service_onhandle)
    }

    // Post a notification indicating whether a doodle was found.
    private void sendNotification(Intent intent) {
        String msg=intent.getStringExtra("MSG");
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
               this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

       /* PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);*/
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,(int) Math.random(),
                intent.setClass(this,MainActivity.class),PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.doodle_alert))
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify((int) Math.random(), mBuilder.build());
    }

//
// The methods below this line fetch content from the specified URL and return the
// content as a string.
//
    /** Given a URL string, initiate a fetch operation. */
    private String loadFromNetwork(String urlString) throws IOException {
        InputStream stream = null;
        String str ="";

        try {
            stream = downloadUrl(urlString);
            str = readIt(stream);
        } finally {
            if (stream != null) {
                stream.close();
            }      
        }
        return str;
    }

    /**
     * Given a string representation of a URL, sets up a connection and gets
     * an input stream.
     * @param urlString A string representation of a URL.
     * @return An InputStream retrieved from a successful HttpURLConnection.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private InputStream downloadUrl(String urlString) throws IOException {

        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Start the query
        conn.connect();
        InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
        return stream;
    }

    /** 
     * Reads an InputStream and converts it to a String.
     * @param stream InputStream containing HTML from www.google.com.
     * @return String version of InputStream.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private String readIt(InputStream stream) throws IOException {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        for(String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine()) 
            builder.append(line);
        reader.close();
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

SampleAlarmReceiver.java as follows

```
package com.example.android.scheduler;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * When the alarm fires, this WakefulBroadcastReceiver receives the broadcast Intent 
 * and then starts the IntentService {@code SampleSchedulingService} to do some work.
 */
public class SampleAlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    // The app's AlarmManager, which provides access to the system alarm services.
    private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    // The pending intent that is triggered when the alarm fires.
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {   
         Log.i("EFAIR","in onReceive ");
        // BEGIN_INCLUDE(alarm_onreceive)
        /* 
         * If your receiver intent includes extras that need to be passed along to the
         * service, use setComponent() to indicate that the service should handle the
         * receiver's intent. For example:
         * 
         * ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), 
         *      MyService.class.getName());
         *
         * // This intent passed in this call will include the wake lock extra as well as 
         * // the receiver intent contents.
         * startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
         * 
         * In this example, we simply create a new intent to deliver to the service.
         * This intent holds an extra identifying the wake lock.
         */

         ComponentName comp = new ComponentName("com.example.android.scheduler", 
                       SampleSchedulingService.class.getName());

                  // This intent passed in this call will include the wake lock extra as well as 
                  // the receiver intent contents.
                  startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        /*Intent service = new Intent(context, SampleSchedulingService.class);

        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, service);*/
        // END_INCLUDE(alarm_onreceive)
    }

    // BEGIN_INCLUDE(set_alarm)
    /**
     * Sets a repeating alarm that runs once a day at approximately 8:30 a.m. When the
     * alarm fires, the app broadcasts an Intent to this WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
     * @param context
     */
    public void setAlarm(Context context,int day,int mongth,int year,int hour,int minute) {
        Log.i("EFAIR","in set alarm"+minute);
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SampleAlarmReceiver.class);
        //put the massage 
        intent.putExtra("MSG","your schedule is going on......");
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,hour+minute+day, intent,0);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        // Set the alarm's trigger time to 8:30 a.m.
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        //calendar.add

        /* 
         * If you don't have precise time requirements, use an inexact repeating alarm
         * the minimize the drain on the device battery.
         * 
         * The call below specifies the alarm type, the trigger time, the interval at
         * which the alarm is fired, and the alarm's associated PendingIntent.
         * It uses the alarm type RTC_WAKEUP ("Real Time Clock" wake up), which wakes up 
         * the device and triggers the alarm according to the time of the device's clock. 
         * 
         * Alternatively, you can use the alarm type ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP to trigger 
         * an alarm based on how much time has elapsed since the device was booted. This 
         * is the preferred choice if your alarm is based on elapsed time--for example, if 
         * you simply want your alarm to fire every 60 minutes. You only need to use 
         * RTC_WAKEUP if you want your alarm to fire at a particular date/time. Remember 
         * that clock-based time may not translate well to other locales, and that your 
         * app's behavior could be affected by the user changing the device's time setting.
         * 
         * Here are some examples of ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP:
         * 
         * // Wake up the device to fire a one-time alarm in one minute.
         * alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 
         *         SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +
         *         60*1000, alarmIntent);
         *        
         * // Wake up the device to fire the alarm in 30 minutes, and every 30 minutes
         * // after that.
         * alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 
         *         AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, 
         *         AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, alarmIntent);
         */

        // Set the alarm to fire at approximately 8:30 a.m., according to the device's
        // clock, and to repeat once a day.
        alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);

        // Enable {@code SampleBootReceiver} to automatically restart the alarm when the
        // device is rebooted.
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, SampleBootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);           
    }
    // END_INCLUDE(set_alarm)

    /**
     * Cancels the alarm.
     * @param context
     */
    // BEGIN_INCLUDE(cancel_alarm)
    public void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
        // If the alarm has been set, cancel it.
        if (alarmMgr!= null) {
            alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
        }

        // Disable {@code SampleBootReceiver} so that it doesn't automatically restart the 
        // alarm when the device is rebooted.
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, SampleBootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
    // END_INCLUDE(cancel_alarm)
}
and SamplebootReceiver.java
package com.example.android.scheduler;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

/**
 * This BroadcastReceiver automatically (re)starts the alarm when the device is
 * rebooted. This receiver is set to be disabled (android:enabled="false") in the
 * application's manifest file. When the user sets the alarm, the receiver is enabled.
 * When the user cancels the alarm, the receiver is disabled, so that rebooting the
 * device will not trigger this receiver.
 */
// BEGIN_INCLUDE(autostart)
public class SampleBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    SampleAlarmReceiver alarm = new SampleAlarmReceiver();
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
        {
            alarm.setAlarm(context,0,0,0,12,45);
        }
    }
}
//END_INCLUDE(autostart)
and MainActivity.java
/*
 * Copyright 2013 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.example1;

import com.example.android.scheduler.R;
import com.example.android.scheduler.SampleAlarmReceiver;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;


/**
 * This sample demonstrates how to schedule an alarm that causes a service to
 * be started. This is useful when you want to schedule alarms that initiate
 * long-running operations, such as retrieving a daily forecast.
 * This particular sample retrieves content from the Google home page once a day and  
 * checks it for the search string "doodle". If it finds this string, that indicates 
 * that the page contains a custom doodle instead of the standard Google logo.
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    SampleAlarmReceiver alarm = new SampleAlarmReceiver();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.sample_output);
        try{
            String msg=getIntent().getStringExtra("MSG");
            tv.setText(msg);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // Menu options to set and cancel the alarm.
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // When the user clicks START ALARM, set the alarm.
            case R.id.start_action:
                alarm.setAlarm(getApplicationContext(),0,0,0,16,35);
                return true;
            case R.id.start_action1:
                alarm.setAlarm(getApplicationContext(),0,0,0,16,37);
                return true;
            case R.id.start_action2:
                alarm.setAlarm(getApplicationContext(),0,0,0,16,19);
                return true;
            case R.id.start_action3:
                alarm.setAlarm(getApplicationContext(),0,0,0,16,21);
                return true;
            case R.id.start_action4:
                alarm.setAlarm(getApplicationContext(),0,0,0,16,23);
                return true;
            case R.id.start_action5:
                alarm.setAlarm(getApplicationContext(),0,0,0,16,25);
                return true;    
            // When the user clicks CANCEL ALARM, cancel the alarm. 
            case R.id.cancel_action:
                alarm.cancelAlarm(this);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I put the MainAcivity.java in same package as in SampleAlarmReceiver then it works fine.otherwise not. my problem is that when I put MainActivity.java in separate package then it not working.any body can help.

Comment: Please show manifest file. I think you didn't mention full package name there.

Answer (score 0):

replace your manifest contents below.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.scheduler"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sample">

    <activity android:name="com.example1.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.example.android.scheduler.SampleAlarmReceiver"></receiver>

    <receiver android:name="com.example.android.scheduler.SampleBootReceiver"
            android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.example.android.scheduler.SampleSchedulingService" />
</application>
```

Comment: I think in all that code the only one thing that matters is missing, the exported property, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

They need to be in the same package unless if you change the option `android:exported="false"` to `true`  or add it if it is not there and your minSdk is higher than 16, i.e for minSdk 17 and above in your AndroidManifest.xml
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html

android:exported

Whether the content provider is available for other applications to use:
true: The provider is available to other applications. Any application can use the provider's content URI to access it, subject to the permissions specified for the provider.
false: The provider is not available to other applications. Set `android:exported="false"` to limit access to the provider to your applications. Only applications that have the same user ID (UID) as the provider will have access to it.
The default value is `"true"` for applications that set either android:minSdkVersion or android:targetSdkVersion to "16" or lower. For applications that set either of these attributes to "17" or higher, the default is "false".

You can set android:exported="false" and still limit access to your provider by setting permissions with the permission attribute.